# Selenuim IDE - Check an input relative to a <td> at the same level

Tags: javascript, selenium

First time here :)

I want to check the input when the text between  is 0139160695.
I tried by using :

```
 Click
//td[text()='0139160695']/ancestor::input[starts-with(@name,'intervsList') and @value='off']
```

it gives me **element not found** but when i use **following or preceding** it works correctly by checking the previous or next checkbox.

```
     <tbody id="yui_3_17_2_1_1499263991011_37905" class="pure-datatable-data">
 <tr id="yui_3_17_2_1_1499263991011_37600" class="pure-datatable-even" data-yui3-record="workOrder_949">

   <td class="pure-datatable-col-selected pure-datatable-cell ">
     <input style="display:none" name="intervsList(58283128)" value="off" type="checkbox">  
   </td>

   <td id="yui_3_17_2_1_1499263991011_37980" class="pure-datatable-col-site pure-datatable-cell ">
     0139160695
    <i class="right icon icon-history etech-workorderlist-history-action" title="Historique"></i>
   </td>

<tr> </tr>
<tr> </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For understanding this, you have to understand the concept of ancestor, parent, following and preceding.

**ancestor:** It gives you all the ancestor elements. We use **ancestor** when we have to find an element on the basis of the parent element. In your example, ancestor elements will be tr,tbody, table and others.

**parent**: It gives you the parent element. In your example, parent element will be **tr**

**This expression is incorrect:**

ancestor::input[starts-with(@name,'intervsList') and @value='off']

as **input** is not the ancestor for **td**.

**XPath which can be used:**

//td[normalize-space()='0139160695']/parent::tr/td/input[@type='checkbox']

Comment: Thank u for your time.

First thing i found was **following::** i tested it nd it worked fine but incorrectly, it marcked the previous number, i told myself why not keep searching on the same context and after i found thoses similaires functions so i tried to use them without any results.

Now what do you suggest !

Comment: If you want to check the checkbox for the element which is prior to that element but not the parent element. You should go for preceding else you should go for following.

Comment: You can use the xpath:"//td[normalize-space()='0139160695']/preceding::input[@type='checkbox']" if there is only one element prior to that element.

Comment: As i said; when i use following or preceding it check the next checkbox or the previous not the the one that i want to check !

i tried xpath:"//td[normalize-space()='0139160695']/preceding::input‌​[@type='checkbox']" and the previous checkbox is checked not the current !

Comment: preceding is used to click the previous checkbox, not the current one. As per the html you have posted, there is not checkbox with the second td. Please give the correct HTML so that I can help you with the solution.

Comment: This is the right HTML ! the checkbox is between the first <td> :
--
`<input style="display:none" name="intervsList(58283128)" value="off" type="checkbox">`
--
ligne 1 : `<tr> <td> <input/> </td> <td> N°1 </td> </tr>`

ligne 2 : `<tr> <td> <input/> </td> <td> N°2 </td> </tr>`

Comment: I have updated the path in my answer. Please use the updated path. It should work